# how do I specify the column in my VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```
For Each c In Range("A2:A157")
    If (Left(c, 1) = "P" Or Left(c, 1) = "T") And IsNumeric(Right(c, 6)) And Len(c) >= 5 Then
        c = "Found It" 'i know this overwrites the value
    End If
Next c
```

I want to write "Found It" on the same Row but column E

I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.Offset`

```
For Each c In Activesheet.Range("A2:A157")
    If (Left(c, 1) = "P" Or Left(c, 1) = "T") And IsNumeric(Right(c, 6)) And Len(c) >= 5 Then
        c.Offset(,4) = "Found It" ' i know this overwrites the value
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Range("E" & c.Row).Value = "Found It"
```